# There are 5 servers. Each server has 1% downtime. What's the probability that at at least three servers are down?

Tags: probability, statistics, mathematical-modeling

There are 5 servers. Each server has $1$% downtime. What's the probability that at at least three servers are down?

My reasoning is the following:

A) There is $(1-0.01)^5$ probability that $5$ from $5$ servers are up

B) Thus, there is $1-(1-0.01)^5$ chance that at least one of $5$ servers is down

C) Similarly there is $1-(1-0.01)^4$ chance that at least one of any $4$ servers is down

D) And $1-(1-0.01)^3$ chance that at least one any $3$ servers is down

Now we can use the points above to calculate the answer:

E) Using B and C we can say that there is $(1-(1-0.01)^5)\cdot(1-(1-0.01)^4$ probability that at least $2$ of them are down (assuming at least one of servers is down, there is $(1-(1-0.01)^4$ probability that one of the rest 4 servers is down as well)

F) Finally, using D and E, there is $(1-(1-0.01)^5)\cdot(1-(1-0.01)^4)\cdot(1-(1-0.01)^3)$ probability that at least $3$ of them are down.

I saw a different answer $(1-\binom{5}{3}\cdot0.01^3)$ in one broadcast, which makes me think that my point E and F are wrong. Could somebody say if any of those answers is correct, and why?

Comment: A and B are right, but C-F all go wrong. **Hint**: If the status of all servers are independent (a pretty large "if" in practice), then the number of servers that are down at any time follows a _binomial distribution_.

Comment: so actually, the 1-(1-Combination(5/3)*0.01^3) is correct? but what if downtime for any server is 99% then the probability is more than one: 1 - (1 - 10 * 0.99^3) > 1

Answer (score 1):

Probability of at least three servers failing is pr(3) + pr(4) + pr(5)

Probability of exactly A servers failing is 
Pr(A) is (5 Choose A) (1%) ^ A * (99%) ^ (5-A)

so if you sum up pr(3) + pr(4) + pr(5) = 0.000009801 + 4.95E-08 + 1.05154E-10 = 0.0009851%

Comment: A curious value for pr(5)?

Answer (score 0):

It is the sum of the following probabilities:

- The probability that exactly $3$ servers are down and the rest are up
- The probability that exactly $4$ servers are down and the rest are up
- The probability that exactly $5$ servers are down and the rest are up

---

So the overall probability is:

$\binom{5}{3}\cdot{(\frac{1}{100})}^3\cdot{(\frac{99}{100})}^2+\binom{5}{4}\cdot{(\frac{1}{100})}^4\cdot{(\frac{99}{100})}^1+\binom{5}{5}\cdot{(\frac{1}{100})}^5\cdot{(\frac{99}{100})}^0=0.0000098511$

Comment: You also need to multiply each term by 99% for each computer that is up.

Comment: @Michael: Correct. Thank you!